# How to export text message data from iCloud

Tags: icloud, messages, apple-id, messages-in-icloud

I've been using iCloud to save text message data for a while now and I'm closing in on 5gb. How do I export this message data into a file or folder for my own personal records?

What I'm **not** trying to do:

- Disable iCloud or stop using it in any way
- Backup & restore my data to a different device
- Do anything with Android
- Mess around with third-party software of any kind (unless it's completely unavoidable)

The **only** relevant objective here:

- Export text message data from iCloud to a file/folder which I control

I spent a while researching this and couldn't find a straight forward/widely agreed upon approach.

Thanks!

Comment: I believe there are lots of 3rd party iOS apps that do this, one seems to be iMazing. Info here https://imazing.com/guide_category/messages (no experience with this app or interest in it.)

Comment: Can't you just copy the 5 GB file to a folder on your hard drive?

Comment: If you have a Mac synced with iMessages, see `~/Library/Messages/Archive/01-02-2019/*.ichat`. The ichat file can be opened by iMessages app on Mac anytime.